# Sync zoom of UIImageView with UIScrollView's viewForZoomingInScrollView:

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, scroll, synchronization

I'm developing some kind of custom map, which will present additional information above map content (I will call it overlay). But overlay rendering very hard process so I render only that part which user can see on the screen at this moment. But I also want when user zoom or pan map, overlay zoom and pan too (without re-rendering, of course, because it require a time to do it). So my overlay is `UIView` with `UIImageView` subview. During user pan I look for `contentOffset` changes (map content presents on `UIScrollView`) and move my `imageView` to that offset (change `origin` of it's `frame`), so this is very quickly. When user detach fingers from screen I set initial `frame` to `imageView` and re-render it. How can I do similar with zoom? I tried monitor for `zoomScale` changes and `contentOffset`, but `imageView` move not like map content. Any suggestion how to do it will be useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my by problem coming from another side to it. Instead of calculating offsets and zoom scales, I add overlay to map content as subview, so it moves and scales with it very good. When user detach fingers from map, I remove it from superview and re-render it